# About the quotient group of degree zero divisors on $C$ by the principal divisors on $C$

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $C$ be an elliptic curve with distinguished point $O$. My **question** is about a mathematical desription of this set denoted by $Pic(C)$ which is the quotient group of degree zero divisors on $C$ by the principal divisors on $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking about is usually denoted $Pic^0(C)$. It is a standard result that this group is isomorphic, as an abstract group, to the elliptic curve $C$ itself. The isomorphism is obtained by taking a divisor class $\sum n_i [P_i]$ and mapping it to the point $\sum n_i P_i$ on $C$ (the sum here being with respect to the group law on $C$).

Comment: The isomorphism is with the rational points of $C$.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog: The curve need not be defined over $\mathbf Q$, in which case there is no such thing as a "rational point". The identification of an elliptic curve with its Jacobian holds over any base field.

Comment: Dear Bruno, I mean the points of $C$ which are rational over the base field $K$: $\mathrm{Pic}^0(C)=C(K)$. For example, if $K$ is finite, than $C(K)$ is finite, but $C$ is infinite.

Comment: Dear @Cantlog: You are right!